# Disabling SKIP_CORRUPT after using DBMS_REPAIR.SKIP_CORRUPT_BLOCKS

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, corruption

Recently I was involved in recovering data after several blocks in production DB got corrupted.

*Disclaimer:* I'm by no means a competent DBA, but rather a PL/SQL developer with quite a bit (I guess) of experience, so maybe I'm missing something quite obvious here. Sorry for that.

`DBMS_REPAIR` package provides the procedure `SKIP_CORRUPT_BLOCKS` which is pretty much self-explanatory (allows accessing table despite it having corrupted blocks).

After it is used you can check `DBA_TABLES.SKIP_CORRUPT` column (which becomes `ENABLED` instead of being `DISABLED` by default).

Now that the dust has settled, all the data has been recovered and, hopefully, lessons has been learnt, I can't seem to find a way to switch it back without recreating the table (if some day another block in this segment gets corrupted, I'd rather have the queries fail than silently skip rows from corrupted blocks).

Is there a way to disable `SKIP_CORRUPT` without recreating the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable it with the same procedure.

```
begin
  dbms_repair.skip_corrupt_blocks
  (
    schema_name => '...',
    object_name => '...',
    object_type => dbms_repair.table_object,
    flags=> dbms_repair.noskip_flag
  );
end;
/
```

`dbms_repair.skip_flag` enables, `dbms_repair.noskip_flag` disables this behaviour.

Comment: Wow! Shame on me, I've no idea how I missed that in docs. Thanks